# Why attributes are in relation in ER diagrams

Tags: entity-relationship

In some ER diagrams there are attributes on the relation.In what occasions should we use attributes on the relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes on relationships allow you to record facts about the relationship as opposed to one of the entities that make up the relationship.  Some examples:

- A marriage between two people has a date and venue
- A student's class allocation may have an assigned seat
- Popularity ratings by customers on products

Here's an ER example of an attribute on a relationship between student and class:
[image: student class seat]

While the semantics of ER seem familiar and aid its popularity, logically the distinction between entities and relationships is artificial and unnecessary.  Entities can have composite keys, and unary relations aren't unusual from an n-ary relational point of view.

Comment: can you explain with an er diagram sample ?

Comment: I hope the diagram example suffices.